# HDMI output from Tango device

Tags: google-project-tango

The initial release notes for Tango stated that the mini HDMI port was not functional.  There has been no statement about HDMI since.  Has anyone tried the HDMI port lately?  Any other known options for getting external video?  I tried using a SlimPort adapter with the USB port with no luck.  I am assuming that since an HDMI port is provided that there is no internal support for SlimPort.  The last time I gave a demo I clipped a webcam on my lapel and pointed it at the screen.  How's that for high tech?  Any better options?

Comment: HDMI on Tango Device is enabled since Descartes Release(20141210)

Answer (score 2):

The HDMI port works fine for me, I am using the dock with it though so perhaps it doesn't work when charging via USB, I'll have to test and see.

Comment: Testing this further, it works for me with direct micro-HDMI cable, (docking station or no) but not coupled with a VGA converter.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the HDMI port with a cable from the device to a TV, mirroring my display. Works fine.

Comment: That is good to know.  I had not tried it yet because I didn't have a mini HDMI cable at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had success with the HDMI port, however I have seen something like this in the past:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/mirroring_an_android_device_screen_onto_your_desktop?lang=en